# Scheme Programming Language Support with Manjaro Arm?

Tags: emacs, raspberry-pi, scheme, lisp, archlinux-arm

I am trying out Manjaro Arm on my Raspberry Pi 3, but surprisingly find only Guile as the only viable Scheme interpreter/REPL.

I have tried the following:

Racket, and Mit-Scheme not found by pacman in the repositories.

Chicken Scheme seems to install, but will only run as the Chicken compiler, the csi REPL is MIA.

[Chibi Scheme](https://github.com/ashinn/chibi-scheme) seems to compile and install fine (and make test ran fine before make install) but then crashes looking for a support file (libchibi-scheme.so.0).

[Chez-Scheme](https://github.com/cisco/ChezScheme) is X86 centric, and no arm fork has been created yet. Historically older versions also ran on Sun SPARC. I did not try to compile or install it.

I would prefer a scheme REPL that is supported by [Geiser](https://www.nongnu.org/geiser/), running within [Emacs](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/).

Comment: Have you tried compiling Racket from source?

Comment: @Flux Not yet, that is next. It seems to be in the repositories for x86 but not arm, as best as I can tell. It does run, (and is apt downloadable) on Raspbian. I am tinkering with Manjaro and therefore indirectly arch because I was looking for a more modern gcc, and clang compiler for C. But now run into issues with my most used language. I will try to compile from source later today.

Comment: Can you explain why Guile is not ok for you? It is supported by Geiser/Emacs.

Comment: Regarding Chicken, I use Manjaro and thought the interpreter wasn't being installed until somehow it dawned on me that the executable name was "chicken-csi" not just "csi".

Answer (score 0):

A couple of years later, and with a new install of Manjaro on a RPi4 (aarch64) I now have managed to install and get the following working:

Racket will compile from source. I had to use the "unix source" only, since "unix source + built packages" still crashed at the attempt at compiling. Compiling the full racket (including DrRacket) source took a few hours on the pi.

Chicken CSI is in the repositories under `chicken-csi`. A soft link in /usr/local/bin with the name csi fixes geiser's search for csi.

Exporting LD_LIBRARY_PATH as an env variable with the location of the chibi-scheme library ( /usr/local/lib/ by default ) makes chibi-scheme fully functional. Chibi-scheme compiled easily on the Rpi4.

Gambit Scheme seems to be in the repositories, although I have not played with it much.

Of course Guile 2.2 is in the repositories and works fine.